# Does Android 13+ require the developer to request for camera runtime permissions?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am building an application but after publishing to Google Play it gets rejected saying permissions needed. Does Android 13+ require to request runtime permissions for it to function well?
[image]

Expecting camera to launch as it does on Android 9

Comment: In short, yes you need to request for runtime permission for camera to operate for Android 6+

Comment: @Israelmikan can you share code which you are using to open camera

Comment: [Reference](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.